# how can I setting the user-agent when in pyside6 WebEngineView

Tags: python, pyside2, pyside6, qwebengineview

I wrote a Windows software in python and pyside6, in which I opened an interface with QwebEngine, is there any way to define the information such as this embedded browser request header

here are my code of this part

```
self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
self.initialUrl = 'http://www.bing.com'
self.webEngineView.load(QUrl(self.initialUrl))
self.right_bottom_layout.addWidget(self.webEngineView, 0, 0)
```

but in windows appplication the web interface is too big is to big and I want to show a mobile web page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJDow.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need to load a QWebEngineHttpRequest with the modified user agent header instead of a url

for example

```
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineHttpRequest


self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
self.initialUrl = 'http://www.bing.com'


user_agent = b"Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.0; Mobile; rv:54.0) Gecko/54.0 Firefox/54.0"
request = QWebEngineHttpRequest()
request.setUrl(self.initialUrl)
request.setHeader(b'user-agent',user_agent)


self.webEngineView.load(request)
self.right_bottom_layout.addWidget(self.webEngineView, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Or also [`setHttpUserAgent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebengineprofile.html#setHttpUserAgent).

Comment: @musicamante  I didn't even know that existed good call

Comment: @musicamante you might want to add that as an alternate answer, I am not familiar with how the WebEngineProfile works.